# How to get the count of a word in a database using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For the same data base, the following 2 codes are showing different answers when executed. According to the answer given the 2nd one is correct but what is the mistake in the 1st code.
**code 1**

```
  df=pd.read_csv("amazon_baby.csv", index_col ="name")
  sw = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']
  for i in sw:
    df[i]=df["review"].str.count(i)
    y=df[i].sum(axis=0)
    print(i,y)
```

**code 2**

```
   df=pd.read_csv("amazon_baby.csv", index_col ="name")
   sw = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']
   df['word_count']=df['review'].apply(lambda x:Counter(str(x).split()))
   def great_count(x):
     if 'great' in x:
        return x.get('great')
     else:
        return 0
  df['great3'] = df['word_count'].apply(great_count)
  print (sum(df['great3']))
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `linear-regression` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

These pieces of code are quite different.

The first one takes each of the words in `sw` list and counts the number of occurences in string. This means that in string "this is great, this is the greatest" for word "great" it will show 2. This is the error, I suppose.

Second code splits the text in separate words: `['this', 'is', 'great,', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'greatest']`, then calculates counts: `Counter({'this': 2, 'is': 2, 'great,': 1, 'the': 1, 'greatest': 1})` and shows the sum of the column.

But!! There is no word "great" in the Counter - this is because of the comma. So this is also wrong.

A better way would be to get rid of punctuation at first. For example like this:

`sum(1 for i in ''.join(ch for ch in t if ch not in string.punctuation).split() if i == 'great')`